# Bootstrap issues with images

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I Have a responsive template working fine.

I use Kunena forums.

I have bootstrap installed for complete responsiveness.

My issue is this, emoticons, when they are in full screen or non-mobile the code looks like this...

```
img width="20" height="20" class="bbcode_smiley" title=";)" alt=";)" 
src="/media/kunena/emoticons/wink.png" style=""
```

As soon as you narrow the screen or are on mobile, "Something" is adapting the code on the fly to this...

```
img width="20" height="20" class="bbcode_smiley" title=";)" alt=";)" 
src="/media/kunena/emoticons/wink.png" style="width: 100%; max-width: 20px; height: auto;"
```

The `width:100%` is what is doing it, but I cannot figure out, if it is the templates code or bootstrap doing this, I don't mind it doing this for "normal" images, just don't want this for any emoticons.

I can also fix it by having: `max-width: 20px !important;`

I just cannot figure out what system is adding the style to the emoticon images, on the fly, so I can then add that `!important` to the max width to fix it etc.

I'm kind of thinking it is either bootstrap or the templates on responsive system.

link as an example: http://www.diveoz.com.au/index.php/forum/hanging-on-the-deco-line/26929-air-pigs.html#299474

to see the issue, find a post with a yellow smiley, and reduce your browser width, once it reaches a point, the smileys explode to 100% width.

Suggestions?

Comment: It's definitely not Bootstrap. Check if there's any JS included in the template you're using, or any other JS you've included that will do this to your emotes

Comment: OK, makes sense. It will be the template. I looked in the files for that, and there is a responsive .js

It has this line... for images...

img.css("width", newWidth).css("max-width", newMaxWidth).css("height", newHeight);

Now how do I edit that, to add the !important after the newmaxwidth etc. Sorry, not a JS programmer.

Comment: You should just be able to comment it out (`// ` at the beginning of the line) or remove it completely.